# can the footer be included on a child theme

Tags: child-theme

If the footer can be included, what must be written on the child theme `footer.php` page to get it started. I should say I am new to child themes and have already shut the site down by including the entire parent stylesheet/functions.php. After reading about that same rookie issue that another member experienced I immediately went to cPanel to delete it.

However before I upload my updated child theme, I'll wait for an answer concerning the `footer.php`. Of course I would like to edit it on my child theme to remove the WordPress branding only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the whole footer.php from the parent theme and copy it to your child theme.  Your child theme will override the parent footer now.  Any changes you make to that footer file  in the child theme (ie removing branding) will affect the site.

This is usually better than starting with a whole new footer.php especially if the theme you are using is overly complex.

As for the style.css and functions.php.  Sorry you had to go through that mess!

Comment: This is not so much a thank you only because it is suggested to avoid those types of comments, but I will say that had I been a member a day or two sooner I would have had a better understanding of how to build/start my first child theme.  Kudo's to WP Stack Exchange.

Just to reiterate;  stylesheet(s) & function.php must be bare bones to start, but footer.php needs no introduction as it is introduced via the parent theme and may include the full footer.php document.  

That's how I'm going to fly with this thing.  I can't wait to experience using the child them method of editing WP sites!

Comment: No worries. We're glad to have you a part of the group.  Feel free to mark an answer (grey check box on the left of an answer) if it has answered your question.

Answer (score 3):

The only things your `footer.php` needs is the `wp_footer(`) function and any html closing tags your theme requires e.g. `</body>` `</html>`.

If would just like to remove some stuff from your parent theme I would recommend you just duplicate that file and remove what you don't want.